# Keeping three cck text multi-value fields and a three-level taxonomy hierarchy in sync

Tags: 7, views, entities

CCK and Taxonomy fields offer different advantages and, in some situations, it is necessary to utilize both. Especially if a developer is using Views and Rules. One of the bigger challenges a developer might encounter is how to manage values that are mirrored in both and how to keep them in sync.

I have a couple of displays for a view that utilize both a three-level hierarchical taxonomy (using Simple Hierarchical Select) for exposed filter input and three CCK list (text) fields that are used only for displaying the selected field values on the frontend, in a table, and in a set of custom breadcrumb links (using a views global custom text field). I would have preferred to do away with the cck fields and render the parent/child Taxonomy term names in the table and breadcrumb links instead, but wasn't successful at it.

In my content type, I would like to synchronize the two types of fields, so that when new values are added to one, they are also added to the other. This would allow me to simplify adding new unique values. I don't care if the taxonomy terms feed into the cck field values, or vice versa.

Has anyone come up with a good solution for this?

Comment: is `%node:field-category:parent:name` field available in views field listing of views ? Here if you are using other field then "field-category" may replace with your field name.

Comment: If I recall correctly that field appeared to be available to the views display, but the output was blank. I will experiment again first thing tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Okay, here's what I've got:

Comment: Okay, here's what I've got:

(1) Added relationship: "Content: My Field Name (field_my_field)";
(2) Added relationships: "Content: Taxonomy terms on node (checked my vocabulary)";
(3) Added field: "field_my_field".

Field doesn't show in view output.

Comment: Correction: the taxonomy field displays, but it's only the child term. Also, I just added the relationship "Taxonomy term: Parent term" and nothing changed.